# Swift UITableViewCell becomes transparent although I never do so in my code

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Why do my UITable cells become transparent? I never make it transparent, never make UITable or UITable cells transparent in my code. However, I can still tap on them, and they react to my taps.

Could you help me solve this problem?

I will provide more information. Please ask in the comment.

P.S. I checked that data I use to fill the content of each cell is intact.

Here's the screenshot of what's happening:[image: table view cells]
I printed the content of cells in `cellForRowAt`, and I could see that they are put into each cell, but it seems blank.
Again, it is weird, but I can tap on any of these cells on my simulator, and it does what I want it to do afterwards.

**Update**

Here's how I create cells:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.accountPostCellIdentifier) as! AccountPostCell
        let post = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.finder.text = post.finder
        cell.id.text = "\(post.id)"
        cell.date.text = post.created_date
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: are you talking about the backgroundColor? backgroundColor of any UIView is transparent by default

Comment: No, I meant the content is transparent.

Comment: Please post the code of how your are creating the cells, and how you are adding its content

Comment: Yes, I'll do that.

Comment: @user17558100 Have you tried setting the `textColor` to black on `finder`, `id` and `data` labels in you `AccountPostCell` cell? The default label `textColor` is white which would cause what you're seeing.

Comment: yes, I did try that. But the result is still the same.

Comment: Have you checked the cells in the view debugger?  It will allow you to determine if they have the correct content and it's not visible, or if it's not there.